# Fix image size in grid.arrange

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am using `grid.arrange` to plot two ggplots side by side (in a single row) in a Jupyter notebook. When I do this the image plotted is too large and the plot height is larger than the screen which looks pretty bad. I want to fix the height (say 2 or 3 inches) of the image. Is there a way to do this?

---

**EDIT**

The code used

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("Base", "Online", "TV",  "Print")),value = c(60, 12, 7, 6))
df_0 <- data.frame( group = as.factor(c("Base")), value = c(100))

plot_left <- ggplot(transform(transform(df, value=value/sum(value)), labPos=cumsum(value)-value/2), 
                    aes(x="", y = value, fill = group)) + geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() + labs(title = "Decompose Sales") + geom_text(aes(y=labPos, label=paste0(round(100*value, 0), "%")), size = 3)

plot_right <- ggplot(transform(transform(df_0, value=value/sum(value)), labPos=cumsum(value)-value/2), aes(x="", y = value)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + coord_polar(theta = "y") + theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Total Sales") + geom_text(aes(y=labPos, label=paste0(round(100*value, 0), "%")), col = "orange", size = 3)

grid.arrange(plot_right+ guides(fill = "none") ,plot_left+ guides(fill = "none"), ncol=2, widths=c(3/10, 3/10))
```

Comment: Please add your code to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: @Alex added the code

Comment: @Alex this is for a jupyter nb

Comment: I don't see the problem in a standard R graphics device. To set the panel size, try `set_panel_size` in various previous answers

Comment: @baptiste the issue is when I am using it in a jupyter notebook. There the images are larger than the screen and I have to scroll

Comment: in that case your question and tags should probably be more specific: the problem is neither with ggplot2 nor R.

Comment: @baptiste updated

Comment: you may want to keep the R tag and some R context, I don't use jupyter but I'm guessing many who do won't have a clue what your code means. (Also, did you try a much simpler piece of graphics, e.g. `grid::grid.rect(height = grid::unit(7, "in"))`? – that would make it easier to follow)